# I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..." spread operator in webview android studio

Tags: javascript, vue.js, android-studio, webview, laravel-mix

the problem is maybe the same as the link below :
https://forum.vuejs.org/t/spread-operator-not-working-in-webview-android/74893/7

but the different is, im using laravel mix and vue 2.6.11

here is my package.json

```
"private": true,
"scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "build-report": "vue-cli-service build --report",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "rename .env .env_ && rename .env_ .env && php artisan ziggy:generate && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js && rename .env .env.production && rename .env_ .env"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.17.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.0",
    "@inertiajs/inertia": "^0.11.0",
    "@inertiajs/inertia-vue": "^0.8.0",
    "@inertiajs/progress": "^0.2.7",
    "@mdi/font": "^4.9.95",
    "@mdi/js": "^5.9.55",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "deepmerge": "^4.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.5.0",
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "laravel-mix": "5.0.9",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "material-design-icons-iconfont": "^6.4.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "sass": "^1.49.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "vuetify": "^2.4.2",
    "vuetify-loader": "1.4.3"
},
"dependencies": {
    "@chenfengyuan/vue-countdown": "^1.1.5",
    "@mdi/light-font": "^0.2.63",
    "@types/ziggy-js": "^0.9.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.4",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.18.0",
    "laravel-echo": "^1.10.0",
    "lottie-player-vue": "0.0.16",
    "object-to-formdata": "^4.1.0",
    "pusher-js": "^7.0.2",
    "qrcode": "^1.5.0",
    "read-excel-file": "^5.2.28",
    "sweetalert2": "^9.17.2",
    "v-money": "^0.8.1",
    "vee-validate": "^2.2.15",
    "vform": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.5",
    "vue-cli": "^2.9.6",
    "vue-countdown": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-excel-xlsx": "^1.2.2",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-qrcode-component": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.5.3",
    "vue-sessionstorage": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-social-auth": "^1.4.9",
    "vue-socket.io": "^3.0.10",
    "vue2-storage": "^5.0.0",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.3",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "vuex-map-fields": "^1.4.1",
    "ziggy": "^2.4.0",
    "ziggy-js": "^1.4.3"
}
```

when i call the url in webview using android studio. it says "[INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..."".
maybe the spread operator called by mistake. ?

here is my webpack.mix.js

```
mix
.webpackConfig({
  
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      vue$: 'vue/dist/vue.runtime.esm.js',
      '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
      ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue')
    }
  },
  plugins: [new VuetifyLoaderPlugin()],
})
.version()
.sourceMaps()
```

i still dont know how to fix this problem.